# eclipse: can't set break point, not working

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to debug a C++ program using Eclipse. For some reason, it doesn't allow me to set a breakpoint. I have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>. But that doesn't work.

Currently, I can only step in and step out. But here is a while loop that terminates until it hits 10000, I can't click that many times....'

PS: when I double click a line, it shows ("add bookmark").

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like [Eclipse bug 511114](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511114) which has already been fixed. How about an upgrade to Eclipse Oxygen?